# Auto clicker UI goes black when started

Tags: java, swing

i have made a simple auto clicker, but when i run it the screen goes black so i cant stop it etc. i dont have a clue what i have done wrong. I thought maybe i had to set focus, but i am not sure.
Code:

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.InputEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;

public class AutoClicker1 extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTextField textField;

    public static int rate;
    public static boolean go = false;
    public static int time;
    public static int multiplyer;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    AutoClicker1 frame = new AutoClicker1();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public AutoClicker1() {
        setTitle("Auto Clicker");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 361, 154);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        JLabel lblNoOfClicks = new JLabel("Interval between clicks");
        lblNoOfClicks.setBounds(10, 25, 149, 14);
        contentPane.add(lblNoOfClicks);

        textField = new JTextField();
        textField.setBounds(10, 55, 139, 20);
        contentPane.add(textField);
        textField.setColumns(10);

        JButton btnStopf = new JButton("Stop(F11)");
        btnStopf.setBounds(203, 45, 89, 23);
        contentPane.add(btnStopf);

        JButton button = new JButton("Stop(F11)");
        button.setBounds(203, 81, 89, 23);
        contentPane.add(button);

        final JRadioButton rdbtnSeconds = new JRadioButton("Seconds");
        rdbtnSeconds.setBounds(6, 81, 65, 23);
        contentPane.add(rdbtnSeconds);

        final JRadioButton rdbtnMilliseconds = new JRadioButton("Milliseconds");
        rdbtnMilliseconds.setBounds(71, 81, 109, 23);
        contentPane.add(rdbtnMilliseconds);
        btnStopf.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                go = false;
            }

        });
        JButton btnStart = new JButton("Start(F10)");
        btnStart.setBounds(203, 11, 89, 23);
        contentPane.add(btnStart);
        btnStart.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                go = true;
                if (rdbtnMilliseconds.isSelected()) {
                    autoClick();
                } else {
                    if (rdbtnSeconds.isSelected()) {
                        multiplyer = 1000;
                        autoClick();
                    }
                }
            }
        });

    }

    private void autoClick() {
        requestFocus();
        rate = Integer.parseInt(textField.getText());
        time = (rate * multiplyer);
        System.out.print(time);
        try {
             Robot robot = new Robot();
             while (true) {
                try {
                   Thread.sleep(rate);
                   robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
                   robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {}
             }
          } catch (AWTException e) {}
    }

    private void keyListner(KeyEvent e) {
        int key = e.getKeyCode();

        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_F10) {
            System.out.print("pressed F10");
            go = true;
        }
        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_F11) {
            go = false;
        }
    }

    private void setTheme() {
        try {
            UIManager
                    .setLookAndFeel("com.seaglasslookandfeel.SeaGlassLookAndFeel");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }

    public static void checkRate() {
        if (rate < 500) {
            rate = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `while(true)` what are you expecting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are blocking [the Event Dispatch Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) in `autoClick()` with the `while(true)`, instead of that you can use a [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html).
I suggest not using keyListener for listen only 2 keys, you can use [keybindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for that purpose. Also you shouldn't call directly `setBounds` rely in a proper [LayoutManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html) to position in screen.

Comment: @WillBaker you still have a few big mistakes, try not using `NULL` layout, cause only would work in your pc.. let that work to layoutManager, i say you to use `SwingTimer` you are using java.util.Timer that is valid too but is preferred to use SwingTimer in swing things, also check that you put `if(go = true)` must be `if (go == true)`

Comment: Ok thanks, I will fix the NULL layout, it is because i used window builder :D

Comment: ohh big mistake, if you are using application by yourself there is no problem , but if has to fix in different pc resizing and etc, it won;t  work properly.. is better to let that work to `LayoutManager`

Comment: Uses a mig layout now, mig is fine yeah. Thanks Guys :)

Answer (score 0):

You break out of the program loop in your Main method when you enter the wile loop in your AutoClick method.

You could instead run your program in a "game loop".

In the main method what I would do is create a method called run()

```
public void run()
{
    int FPS = 60;

    float startTime =  System.currentTimeInMillis();

    while(started)
    {  
        float currentTime = System.currentTimeInMillis();
        float passedTime = currentTime - startTime;

        startTime = System.currentTimeInMillis();

        if(passedTime > (float) 1000/FPS)
          { 
           update();
          }
    }  
}
```

and then in the update method put the logic of the program. I know it is a totally different approach to how you are currently doing it but in my opinion it allows for more flexibility.

For example in your action listener you could have it invoke a "startClick()" method
where it sets a boolean value to true and initializes what you intialzie currently in the autoclick method. Then your update() method would look like this:

```
public void update()
{
  if(boolean) //boolean value that startClick sets to true
    {
      robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
      robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
    }
}
```

This way the program isn't stuck in an infinite while-loop and you can control how often it updateswith the FPS variable.

Comment: Thanks but i fixed it before i saw your post :)